# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{rn}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis

For an integer $\,r,\,$ let
$$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{rn}\,\frac{\sin nx}{n^2}.$$
Then we need to prove $f(x)$ is convergent for every $x\in\Bbb R$ and every integer $r$.

My approach is to consider $\,a(n)=\dfrac1{n^2}\,$ and $\,b(n)=(-1)^n\sin(nx).$

The series $\;\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac1{n^2}\;$ is bounded and convergent and the sequence $\;b(n)=(-1)^n\sin(nx)\,$ oscillates between positive and negative values as $\,n\,$ increases, but its magnitude is bounded.

Is the approach correct and how to incorporate $\,r\,$ in the solution?

Comment: Easy approach:  $|(-1)^{rn}\frac{sinnx}{n^2}|\le \frac{1}{n^2}$.  Dominant convergence.

Comment: This answers your question: [Determine convergence of series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159477/determine-convergence-of-series) (the series is not exactly the same but the argument is).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, $\left((-1)^n\sin(nx)\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a *bounded* sequence, for eqch $x\in\mathbb{R}$, since, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\left|(-1)^n\sin(nx)\right|\le1$. More generally, $\left((-1)^{rn}\sin(nx)\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a bounded sequence (the absolute value of every element of the sequence is smaller than or equal to $1$). So,
$$
\left|(-1)^{nr}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n^2}\right|\le\frac1{n^2}
$$
and therefore your series converges absolutely. So, it is convergent.